# SharePoint library not to ask for document title

Tags: 2013

how I need to force `upload.aspx` to not redirect user to update title of document ?

When user now uploads  a document and click on upload i dont want user to update title but that is it.

Any setting there ?

Comment: so what should the title be then?

Comment: Name of document but if i addo a event receiver would that be enough for not redirecting user ??

Comment: what if you edit the library so that the title field is not required?

Comment: @Gwny please add your comment as a answer so I could down vote it. thank you

Comment: that's why it is a comment and not an answer..

Comment: I was saying joking, title is a must field but my document library has it as not required